# jQuery compatibility issues with IE8 and lower

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

In developing this site for a friend, I have come across serious issues rendering jQuery in IE 8 and earlier. I am still quite new to the web developer scene, and am at a complete loss as to what is occurring. a copy of the site can be found at [cat5andmouse.com/phillipeldermusic](http://cat5andmouse.com/phillipeldermusic)

The audio player is a modified version of something freely available, and the column switching of content was coded by hand.

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Please be more specific with your question

Comment: JQuey team while not support IE8

Comment: You have js error `$.browser.msie' is null or not an object` jQuery 1.8 doesn't support `$.browser` and therefore the player ie detection might not work!!!

Comment: Is there a reason why you're loading 2 jQuery libraries? 1.8.0 and 1.9.1

Comment: Be sure to use jQuery 1.9 or lower. jQuery 2 does not support "old IE" which means it will not work right.

Comment: @TaronPro: It's only the 2.x branch that doesn't support IE8.

Comment: @Guffa: No, current version also not support

Comment: @TaronPro no 1.9 does have IE8 support  http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/

Comment: But dont have support $.browser.msie

Comment: remove or comment out `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and see if it works - This is the 1.9.1 library which doesn't support $.browser

Comment: @wirey and others: advising to use older *software* versions is never a good idea!!

Comment: @TaronPro As kidwon pointed out jQuery 1.8 does not support `$.browser`. jQuery however does support IE 8. It supports all the way back to IE 6. Please review this reference [chart](http://jquery.com/browser-support/). There is a difference between not supporting a feature and not supporting a browser.

Comment: @TaronPro: It doesn't support `$.browser.safari`, `$.browser.webkit`, `$.browser.opera` or `$.browser.mozilla` either. I guess jQuery doesn't support any browsers at all as of version 1.9. ;)

Comment: @kidwon wrote:  _"jQuery 1.8 doesn't support $.browser"_ ~ [I think you meant jQuery 1.9](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have js error 
`$.browser.msie' is null or not an object`

jQuery 1.9 doesn't support `$.browser` and therefore the player ie detection might not work!!!

Try older version of jQuery like 1.7 and below and see what happens

Comment: And why not jQuery **1.8.3**?  See:  http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/

Comment: **jQuery 1.8.3** will work in this scenario. Better use this.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery 1.9+ doesn't Support jQuery.browser, however, you can bring it back with jQuery's <del>browser implementation:  https://github.com/jquery/jquery-browser</del> migrate plugin http://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

BTW: Killing default browser behaviors is never a good idea ;-) in your case the history-support.

Comment: did you read the link you provided?  It said the plugin is no longer maintained and you should be using [jquery.migrate](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)

Comment: @mattcoker Is your question answered now? Then mark it as it is... :)